How can I add add row to matrix in numba
I need to add a 'row' an array (1x4) to matrix(Nx4) in Numba
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def loop_append(arr, row_arr):
    arr2 = arr.copy()
    for i in range(5):
        arr2 = np.append(arr2,row_arr)

    return arr2




# Creating a numpy array of random floats with size 10x4
arr = np.random.rand(10, 4)
row_arr = np.random.rand(1, 4)

arr2 = loop_append(arr,row_arr)

print(arr2)

But I get this error. I have tried vstack and concatenate too.
Error:
Cannot unify array(float64, 2d, C) and array(float64, 1d, C) for 'arr2.2', defined at C:\Test\numba_append.py (7)

File "numba_append.py", line 7:
def loop_append(arr, row_arr):
    <source elided>
    arr2 = arr.copy()
    for i in range(5):
    ^

During: typing of assignment at C:\Test\numba_append.py (7)

File "numba_append.py", line 7:
def loop_append(arr, row_arr):
    <source elided>
    arr2 = arr.copy()
    for i in range(5):
    ^


Process finished with exit code 1


If you run this code without the njit decorator, you will get a 1D array of shape (60,) , but what you actually want is (15, 4) , correct?

Correct. Adding new rows to the bottom

You should really never use np.append in a loop so to grow iteratively a Numpy array. This is an anti-pattern and it will always be very inefficient since it recreate a new array every time, which has a quadratic execution time. Numba cannot solve this problem. You need to preallocate the array at the right size.

Regarding your problem, array are typed in Numba and the number of dimension is a part of the type. np.append like all Numba functions operate on typed arrays. Since the former is a 2D array, maybe Numba expect the later to be a 2D array/view. You can certainly reshape the 1D array to get a 2D one but the best is simply to preallocate the final array and copy the blocks directly into it for sake of performance (and clarity IMHO).

Short Answer:
Just add axis=0.
@njit
def loop_append(arr, row_arr):
    arr2 = arr.copy()
    for i in range(5):
        arr2 = np.append(arr2, row_arr, axis=0)  # Added axis=0.

    return arr2

Long Answer:
According to the official documentation for np.append:

If axis is not given, both arr and values are flattened before use.

This means that in your original code (without the axis argument), the return value of np.append is a 1D array. However, you are trying to reassign it to arr2, which was a 2D array. Numba treats 1D and 2D arrays as different types, so this operation won't work.
@njit
def loop_append(arr, row_arr):
    arr_2d = arr.copy()
    for i in range(5):
        arr_1d = np.append(arr_2d, row_arr)

        # You are trying to assign a 1D array to a 2D array variable here.
        arr_2d = arr_1d

    return arr_2d

This is what the error message complains about.
Cannot unify array(float64, 2d, C) and array(float64, 1d, C) for 'arr2.2', ...
                            ^^                        ^^

So, what you need to do is make sure that the number of dimensions of the array does not change before and after you add a row.
Additionally, as pointed out in the comments, np.append creates a new array and performs a deep copy. This is not something to worry about with a single add operation, but it is if you use it repeatedly. Especially when dealing with large arrays or adding many rows, it can have a significant impact on performance.
Here is the benchmark:
import timeit

import numpy as np
from numba import njit


@njit
def loop_append(arr, row_arr, n):
    if n == 0:
        return arr.copy()

    arr2 = arr  # No need for a copy here.
    for i in range(n):
        arr2 = np.append(arr2, row_arr, axis=0)

    return arr2


@njit
def loop_preallocate(arr, row_arr, n):
    assert row_arr.ndim == 2 and row_arr.shape[0] == 1
    arr2 = np.empty((arr.shape[0] + n, arr.shape[1]), dtype=arr.dtype)
    arr2[:arr.shape[0]] = arr
    for i in range(n):
        arr2[arr.shape[0] + i] = row_arr

    return arr2


def test():
    arr = np.random.rand(10000, 100)
    row_arr = np.random.rand(1, 100)
    n = 10

    r1 = loop_append(arr, row_arr, n)
    r2 = loop_preallocate(arr, row_arr, n)
    assert r1.shape == (arr.shape[0] + row_arr.shape[0] * n, arr.shape[1])
    assert np.array_equal(r1, r2)

    def benchmark(f):
        number, time_taken = timeit.Timer(lambda: f(arr, row_arr, n)).autorange()
        print(f"{f.__name__}: {1000 * time_taken / number:.3f} ms")

    benchmark(loop_append)
    benchmark(loop_preallocate)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()

loop_append: 15.892 ms
loop_preallocate: 1.831 ms

